# How do I see linux kernel SNMP counters?

Tags: linux, kernel, snmp

The kernel has a bunch of SNMP counters it increments under various situations, and I want to get the current values on my system. I found `nstat`, but that does not show all the counters (even with the `-z` option). For example, I want to see the value of "XfrmInStateSeqError", which is incremented in net/xfrm/xfrm_input.c:

```
if (async && x->repl->check(x, skb, seq)) {
  XFRM_INC_STATS(net, LINUX_MIB_XFRMINSTATESEQERROR);
  goto drop_unlock;
}
```

The system in question is Ubuntu 12.04 running kernel 3.2.0.

Comment: `cat /proc/net/xfrm_stat | grep XfrmInStateSeqError`

Comment: That looks promising but my system doesn't have that file. Does something need to be enabled before I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Debian it is just not compiled with kernel :

```
grep XFRM_STATISTICS /lib/modules/3.1.0-1-amd64/build/.config
# CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS is not set
```

hence no /proc/net/xfrm_stat

i guess setting CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS and recompiling kernel will do it...

Comment: `grep XFRM_STATISTICS /boot/config-3.2.0-3-amd64
# CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS is not set` for getting config directly from boot information for right kernel.